# Adding Delimiter to Each Row of Input in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have problem with inputting and getting the values out.  The input requires me to input Debit amount and Remarks and I can always add a row if there is more than one items to input.  The issue I'm having now is that the default delimiter is comma and my Remarks field contains comma as well.  As such,the Remarks is split incorrectly.

E.g.

```
Row            Code               Amount           Remarks
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1              LPENALTY            200.00          Late payment penalty, 13Mar2014
2              CURFEE             1200.00          Additional items
3              PROCFEE             150.00          Processing fee undercharged, was previously charged 100.00 only
```

The report that I'm getting from these input are:

```
LPENALTY      200.00       Late payment penalty
CURFEE       1200.00       13Mar2014
PROCFEE       150.00       Additional items
```

I have the below declarations and assignments:

```
Dim strCodeArr() As String
Dim strDebitArr() As String
Dim strRemarksArr() As String

    strCodeArr = Split(Request("FeeCode"), ",")
strRemarksArr = Split(Request("Remarks"), ",")
strDebitArr = Split(Request("Debit"), ",")

..
..
..
..
            For i = 0 To UBound(strDebitArr)
                If strDebitArr(i) <> "" Then
                    objAcc.AccountItems(x).Code = CDec(strCodeArr(i))
                    objAcc.AccountItems(x).Amount = CDec(strDebitArr(i))
                    objAcc.AccountItems(x).Remarks = strRemarksArr(i)

                    x = x + 1
                End If
            Next
..
..
..
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you show how you enter your raw data.

Answer (score 0):

If you check how many items are in the split, you can react to when commas are in the remarks.

Below is a basic function to do this, and return an array of 3 items:

```
Private Function ParseLine(ByVal rowString As String) As String()

    Dim result(2) As String
    Dim parsedItems() As String

    parsedItems = rowString.Split(",")
    If UBound(parsedItems) = 2 Then
        ' No commas in remarks
        result = parsedItems
    Else
        result(0) = parsedItems(0)
        result(1) = parsedItems(1)
        For index = 2 To UBound(parsedItems)
            If index > 2 Then
                ' Prefix with comma (removed in Split)
                result(2) &= ","
            End If

            ' Append each string in split
            result(2) &= parsedItems(index)
        Next
    End If

    Return result

End Function
```

A better way would be to enclose any data with commas in quotation marks, to mirror CSV handling.

```
Late payment penalty, 13Mar2014    -->    "Late payment penalty, 13Mar2014"
```

Then you can create a CSV parser which operates on a single line, and be reuseable in other applications.

You can go one better and make this a string extension:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module MyExtensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function ParseCSVLine(ByVal stringValue As String) as String
        Dim result as String

        ' Code to parse a single line

        return result
    End Sub

End Module
```

This way every string variable now has a ParseCSVLine() method:

```
For Each rowLine In rowItems
    Console.WriteLine(rowLine.ParseCSVLine())
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have this input data:

```
LPENALTY,200.00,Late payment penalty, 13Mar2014
CURFEE,1200.00,Additional items
PROCFEE,150.00,Processing fee undercharged, was previously charged 100.00 only
```

You want to split on commas, but the remarks also have commas.

So this would be my approach. Start with your data:

```
Dim data = New String() _
{ _
    "LPENALTY,200.00,Late payment penalty, 13Mar2014", _
    "CURFEE,1200.00,Additional items", _
    "PROCFEE,150.00,Processing fee undercharged, was previously charged 100.00 only" _
}
```

Then apply this query:

```
Dim query = _
    From d In data _
    Let ds = d.Split(","C) _
    Select New With _
    { _
        .Code = ds(0), _
        .Amount = Decimal.Parse(ds(1)), _
        .Remarks = String.Join(",", ds.Skip(2)) _
    }
```

And I get this kind of result:

[image: results]